# How to log in as guest user via terminal?

Tags: 12.10, permissions, guest-session

I need to login as a guest user via a terminal for experimental purposes for checking the working of one of scripts.

I know I can log in as a different user using `su username` or `su - username`. However, I can't log in using this command as `su guest`. I can auto-complete this as `su guest-<some_id>`, but this asks for a password I am unaware of.

How do I login, then, as the guest user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu "guest users" [are added and deleted on the fly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227261/how-do-i-set-a-password-for-guest-login). They are account without passwords (and locked so). You can find details on guest user also on [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).

If you want a fixed guest user, you should create one (you can do this via the control settings graphic interface of via commandline with [`adduser`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd/345986#345986))